# Weka - semi supervised learning - how to label data and get back the result?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I have just started to use Weka and I would like to ask you. I have installed a collective classification package and i have a simple training data.

```
X Y Label
--------------------
1 2 Class 1
3 2 Class 1
3 3 Unknown class
4 2 Unknown class
11 12 Unknown class
15 20 Unknown class
```

Is it possible somehow get data back from Weka labeled? Maybe I don't understand the semi-supervised method because in my opinion it's used to label other data if I have labeled a little subset.

In my case, I would like to annotate several normal instances, get label other similar instances and in the end detect anomaly instances..

Thank you your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you would like to store the predicted labels of your model into your missing labels.

What you could do is right-click on the Model after training, then select 'Visualize Classifier Errors'.    In this visualization screen, set Y as the predicted class and then save the new ARFF.  This datafile should then contain the predicted and class labels.

From there, you could try to replace the Missing Values with the predicted labels.

I hope this assists in the problem that you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you whether you have experiences with with weka semi-supervised collective classification? I'm wondering  how to create a proper dataset and how to properly label instances without class?

Comment: I have just loaded a dataset from mysql database and I have read that to have unlabeled instance it's necessary to set class to "?". But it is still considered as a class. It's weird or am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct, setting the class value to ? should result in a missing value.  Perhaps the values are stored in the ARFF as '?' or "?" instead, thereby causing a value instead?

Comment: That's the problem. I have manually repair it in the file but is it possible to read it somehow from db and prevent from considering ? in varchar attribute as a class label? Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you need to find a way to convert these cases to non-text values.  Find and Replace All "?" to ? would be possible with a text editor, but if you are programmatically doing this, it should be possible to recode depending on your implementation.